# Is btrfs's 'parent id' and 'top level' different?

Tags: btrfs

Here's a subvolume list of openSuse system.

```
# btrfs subvolume list -p /mnt/openSuse/
ID 256 gen 479 parent 5 top level 5 path @
ID 258 gen 479 parent 256 top level 256 path var
ID 259 gen 307 parent 256 top level 256 path usr/local
ID 260 gen 479 parent 256 top level 256 path tmp
ID 261 gen 272 parent 256 top level 256 path srv
ID 262 gen 480 parent 256 top level 256 path root
ID 263 gen 325 parent 256 top level 256 path opt
ID 264 gen 479 parent 256 top level 256 path home
ID 265 gen 272 parent 256 top level 256 path boot/grub2/x86_64-efi
ID 266 gen 272 parent 256 top level 256 path boot/grub2/i386-pc
```

parent and top level is always the same. (5=5 for @, 256=256 for others)
Is it the same one?

One more thing. What does the gen(generation id) mean?

Answer (score 1):

The following is documented in `man btrfs-subvolume`:

> For every subvolume the following information is shown by default: ID, gen, top level, and path where:
>
> ID is subvolume’s id,
>
> gen is an internal counter which is updated every transaction
>
> top level is the same as parent subvolume’s id
>
> and path is the relative path of the subvolume to the top level subvolume.

Consider these examples from your question:

```
ID 256 gen 479 parent 5 top level 5 path @
ID 258 gen 479 parent 256 top level 256 path var
```

The subvolume @ has a parent of 5 because that's the ID of the top-level subvolume (not shown in the list). Subvolume var has a parent of 256 because it's within the @ subvolume. Yes, parent and "top level" should be the same.